# One installer file to install .msi and python

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have application made in Visual Studio C# app.
I've created installer .msi one file which works just perfect.
Problem here is my application require python to be used, so i somehow need to put inside my installation python among with app.

Is it possible to create one installer which will install python and then my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we use MSI packages to deploy python-based apps. Are you using Visual Studio to build the MSI?

[- Create MSI for Python application](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/create-msi-python-executable.html)

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: thank you for your reply. But here is not the point to compile .py file into exe. I would love to stick to the .py file actually , that means i want to install python on end user pc who will be running py files, instead of compiling them

Comment: In this case you need the Python installer. You can add that installer as a prerequisite in your setup package, as explained here: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites

Comment: Advance installer having any expire date